# iOS UITableView not displayed

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have inherited some old iOS code and have attempted to integrate it into a new iOS 6 application.  I have implemented most of the code and so far everything has worked.  I'm now working on the last bit of that old code.  I'm implementing a set of views to show a rss for a news section of my app.  I've implemented the categories view, which upon selecting an item would display the individual items within that category.  However nothing gets displayed.  I've made all the modifications that I'm aware of that I needed to do, however I'm no expert at iOS development and am in need of some guidance.  Below is a snapshot of the simulator as it's attempting to display the view, and below that is a copy of my .h and .m files.  I don't know what is preventing anything in the table from showing up.  And preemptive thanks to any help!

here's the snapshot of the simulator

[image: snapshot]

Here is a snapshot of the storyboard showing the linking to the Table View

[image: snapshot2]

Here's the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BlogRssParser.h"

@class BlogRssParser;
@class BlogRssParserDelegate;
@class BlogRss;
@class XMLCategory;

@interface NewsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate, BlogRssParserDelegate> {
    BlogRssParser * _rssParser;
    XMLCategory * _currItem;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) BlogRssParser * rssParser;
@property (readwrite, retain) XMLCategory * currItem;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *itemTableView;

@end
```

Here is my .m file

```
#import "NewsViewController.h"
#import "NewsDetailsViewController.h"
#import "BlogRssParser.h"
#import "BlogRss.h"
#import "XMLCategory.h"

#define kLabelTag 1;

@interface NewsViewController ()

@end

@implementation NewsViewController

@synthesize rssParser = _rssParser;
@synthesize currItem = _currItem;

- (void)navBarInit {
    UIBarButtonItem *refreshBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                         initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
                                         target:self action:@selector(reloadRss)];

    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:refreshBarButton animated:YES];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.itemTableView.delegate = self;
    self.itemTableView.dataSource = self;

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self navBarInit];
    [self.itemTableView reloadData];
    self.itemTableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;    
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    _rssParser = [[BlogRssParser alloc]init];
    _rssParser.delegate = self;

    [[self rssParser]startProcess:[_currItem categoryId]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)reloadRss{
    [[self rssParser]startProcess:[_currItem categoryId]];
    [[self itemTableView]reloadData];
}

- (void)processCompleted{
    [[self itemTableView]reloadData];
//  _tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [[self itemTableView]setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}

-(void)processHasErrors{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Title" message:@"Unable to retrieve the news. Please check if you are connected to the internet."
                                                   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[[self rssParser]rssItems]count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    const CGFloat LABEL_TITLE_HEIGHT = 70.0;
    const CGFloat LABEL_WIDTH = 210.0;

    NSString * mediaUrl = [[[[self rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]mediaUrl];
    NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mediaUrl]];
    UIImage * imageFromImageData;
    if (imageData == nil) {
        imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.urlForImage.image.png"]];
    }
    imageFromImageData = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];


    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"rssItemCell"];
    if(nil == cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"rssItemCell"];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        UILabel * _topLabel =
        [[UILabel alloc]
         initWithFrame:
         CGRectMake(
                    imageFromImageData.size.width + 10.0,
                    0.0,
                    LABEL_WIDTH,
                    LABEL_TITLE_HEIGHT)];


        _topLabel.tag = kLabelTag;
        _topLabel.opaque = NO;
        _topLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        _topLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _topLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        _topLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0];
        _topLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]];
        _topLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:_topLabel];
    }

    cell.imageView.image = imageFromImageData;

    UILabel * topLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    topLabel.text = [[[[self rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]title];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NewsDetailsViewController *tlc = [[DetailsViewController alloc]init];
    tlc.currentItem = [[[self rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    tlc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self presentViewController:tlc animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not get a conclusion about the problem you are facing.

But here are few things you should check.

Because i cannot see even an empty table view in your screenshot

1. Do you have the TableView on the Nib file ?
2. It is mapped from The Nib file to the IBOutlet itemTableView ?

Comment: I was going to add the same comment, make sure in viewDidLoad that  self.itemTableView is not nil.  If it is, you didn't link it in interface builder.

Comment: I'm using a storyboard, but it is linked.  I'll have to double check just to make sure though.  and to make doubly sure I'll unlink it and relink it back up.  Thanks for the suggestion, I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: I have double checked that the Table View is on the storyboard viewcontroller and is mapped to the IBOutlet itemTableView, however from @KendallHelmstetterGelner comment about checking self.itemTableView, well it is nil.  I have added the storyboard item showing that the table View is linked.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make a method in that class for setItemTableView, add an NSLog and set a breakpoint every time the value is set.  Then hopefully you could see it being set by the storyboard, and also by whatever is setting it to nil.

Comment: So I programatically added the UITableView to the class in the ViewDidLoad method and that finally resolved the issue. regardless of the storyboard linking. 

-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
_tableView.dataSource = self;
 _tableView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview: _tableView];
 }

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is make sure that `[[[self rssParser] rssItems] count]` is actually returning > 0. Also, is this a copy&paste of your .m file? viewDidLoad is missing the closing brace, but Xcode would catch that.

Answer (score 0):

Add at least one table view cell (Drag and drop one prototype cell).. 
like this
[image] [image]

Then select that cell and give some name in "Reuse Identifier" with this identifier allow datasource..